# String and attributions problems

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Ive been messing around with this without proper results. My code is as follows

```
NSMutableAttributedString *nameString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:((User *)appDelegate.users[self.currentUserIndex]).name];
[nameString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, nameString.length)];

NSString *adviceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, remember be extra aware of the \n cat today. The dog index is 4, dogcatcher \n suggests you should at minimum wear \n a dog and apply cat...", [nameString string]];
```

So, it doesn't bold the username as desired. I tried using `NSAttributedString` for adviceString but then I can't use the `initWithFormat:` method and list the variables after the string, and I don't see any `NSAttributedString` equivalent. I wanted to you `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSMutableAttributedString`, but it doesn't seem to recognise the `addAttribute:value:fontWithName:range` method. Can anybody help me out? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why not insert attributed string into your `adviceString`, which should also be attributed. Otherwise it will not hold the attributes. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to have 4 variables that I can make bold and insert them to my standard string

Comment: For that you **cannot** use `NSString`. `NSAttributedString` is the way to go.

Comment: yea, I found out that I can't even appendByAttributedString: basicNSString. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's for sure, you need to use NSAttributedString also for `adviceString` to get attributed.

The code goes like this, if you need to use `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString *fullName = @"Anoop Kumar Vaidya";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedName = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", fullName]
                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]}];
```

In the attributes you can add few more desired/required attributes.

EDIT 2:

You may like to use some methods as :

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString *)normalString:(NSString *)string{
    return [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                  attributes:@{}];
}

-(NSMutableAttributedString *)boldString:(NSString *)string{
    return [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]
                                                               }];
}
```

And then use them as per your requirement:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedName = [self boldString:fullName];
[attributedName appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@" is creating one"]];
[attributedName appendAttributedString:[self boldString:@" bold"]];
[attributedName appendAttributedString:[self normalString:@" string."]];
```

Comment: could you please correct your answer so it contains, say 3, variables that can take bold size and then adding it to a plain string. Your example helped me, but it bolds the whole string which isn't intentional

Comment: seems to make sense and gave me some ideas (even though it seems a difficult way to do a simple thing), thank you! I think you should replace "string" in your last code section with perhaps anNSAttributedString just for clearance and no misunderstandings.